# <strong><a> or <a><strong>?

Tags: html, tags, nested

Which is the best practice when nesting inline and anchor tags?

`<strong><a href="">link</a></strong>` or `<a href=""><strong>link</strong></a>`

Surprisingly enough I haven't found the answer here or googling it.

Comment: I've always gone with the strong inside the a - not sure why other than it means I can format the link in part if I wished.

Comment: Is your question about SEO or HTML?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

None is correct.

If it's just a matter of styling the entire `<a>` tag in bold, do it using CSS and leave the `<strong>` tag where it would have a significant semantic meaning.

`<a>` tags have a specific meaning and just bolding them all up won't change that meaning.

Comment: I'd give this +100 if I could.

Comment: Not always true; i.e. when using screen reading software; you may wish to draw attention to a key phrase within a link. Otherwise, I agree.

Comment: This is what I actually did before you posted this answer, since this was the situation. But yet there are times when you will want to stress AND link a word or group of words, in which case the question remains the same.

Comment: There is no clash semantically between something that could be a link and the possibility of putting emphasis on something — they are not mutually exclusive. As such, both are correct.

The author didn't say that the reason they were using strong was purely for aesthetics so there's no reason to make that assumption —  as such, I would say 'either are correct' rather than 'neither is correct'.

Comment: Totally agree with @anotherdave here. Saying "none is correct" is quite misleading in this case and suggests that you are not allowed at all to mark up text the way OP did.

Answer (score 17):

My interpretation of the [HTML 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866) standard is, that
`<a><strong></strong></a>` would be correct:

> 5.7. Phrase Markup
>
> Phrases may be marked up according to idiomatic usage, typographic
> appearance, **or for use as hyperlink anchors**.

Comment: This seems to be the most correct answer when it comes to directly answering the question.

Answer (score 8):

from the SEO point of view, both are bad, the correct form is:

```
<a href="">in a relevant phrase a <strong>relevant</strong>link</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer is, either is fine, really as they are inline elements.

However, if you want to make the contents of the entire anchor bold, I would but it outside; this is more of a scope thing - I am making it clear I want any children of this element to be bold.

I would put strong tags inside the link only when I wanted to embolden a part of the link (perhaps click **here**) for example.

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference, for instance if your stylesheet defines:

```
a {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

If you put the `<a>` within the `<strong>` element the link will not be bold, if you put the `<strong>` tags within the `<a>` it will. In my view `<strong>` should be inside `<a>`.

EDIT: Please note that I'm not advising anyone to do this, I'm just pointing out that there are cases in which the order of the tags does make a visible difference. As Mihalis Bagos pointed out; I think it will be best to omit the `<strong>` tag if the entire link will be bold.

Comment: I agree, kzh, I was just pointing out that, depending on your style sheet the order in which `<a>` and `<strong>` appear makes a difference. I'm not advising anyone to use the code I posted.

Answer (score 2):

Other things being equal, `<strong><a href="">link</a></strong>` is slightly better, since then the innermost markup is for a link and this helps to keep link appearance consistent. Some day, someone might want to set a color for strongly emphasized texts, i.e. for `<strong>` elements. A simple color assignment would then not affect the color of strongly emphasized links, letting link colors prevail – and things like different colors for visited, unvisited, hovered, and active links can be essential to usability.

But if you nest them the other way around, you just need to be more careful in styling.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you want to change the content of the link later with javascript. Putting the strong around the a will make sure the new content is displayed strong too.

Comment: No. `<strong>` elements have specific semantic meaning. You don't just use them where you think it would be handy.